# Desktop Background Scaling and RAM usage

Tags: desktop, desktop-customization, image-processing

I've been setting my wallpaper on all my computers to just a single pixel image, in order to conserve RAM for more important uses. But I wonder if, in the process of the OS scaling the image to screen size, that it just uses up that amount of RAM anyways? Anybody know how that works?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What problem are you actually facing? If your system is suffering from low memory it would be better to solve *that* problem.

Comment: i know, but that costs money. plus, some devices, you can't expand your ram. i just wanna know if this is a wasted effort and i should just embrace desktop wallpapers or not.